# Error: EROFS: read-only file system with fs.createWriteStream

Tags: node.js

I've got Node.js/Fastify porject setup in Docker. I'm trying to create a blank CSV file but I keep getting the error `Error: EROFS: read-only file system`

All I have in my function is  `const ws = fs.createWriteStream("reports/test.csv")`

What am I missing here?

Comment: Do you have enough space on your hard drive? Seems like this problem can be related with [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37752455/read-only-file-system-error-when-pulling-docker-image)

Comment: Plenty of space available @Jaood_xD. I can create files from the terminal, it's just the JS code that won't create an empty file.

Comment: The relative path resolves to a read-only file system. You can't write to a read-only file system. Why it is read-only isn't clear. We can't tell what the full path is and we don't know how your Docker image is configured.

Comment: I have posted the answer. Was an oversight on my part.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. My docker-compose.yml had 'ro' (readonly).

```
volumes:
    - ./:/app:ro
```

Removed the 'ro' and it's worked.